# Nothing happens when I reach the tower entrance

Tags: ys-origin

[image]

This is where the game gets to, and soft-hangs, every time. By "soft-hang" I mean the animations and sounds play normally, but nothing actually happens no matter what buttons I press or how long I wait.

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game launcher doesn't seem to offer a way to play in windowed mode, but hitting Alt-Enter did the trick and so that's what I did to <s>suffer through</s> watch the cutscenes.

When I *didn't* do that, the tower entrance area started just fine. I played in windowed mode without obvious trouble for some time afterwards.

Answer (score -1):

If it is your first time coming there (from the outside), that is the place where you get the first tutorials and meet the first people of the away team.

If it hangs here, I guess the data must be corrupted and a reinstall or data verification is in order.

Comment: I was skeptical, but "1 file failed to be validated and will be reacquired."

Comment: ...and I'm still stuck there :(

Comment: It's been since I had it installed, so I'm really not sure now. But if I remember correctly, the whole Falcom engine had a lot of customizability before you launch it - I'd try jiggling with all the stuff you can find, running in fullscreen/windowed, different controllers. I'm really drawing a blank here with what to do now.